# override save and clean method in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

hello i have `StoreCheckout` model and i override save and clean method but conditions  in override methods not work.

```
class StoreCheckout(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Store,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={
            'is_confirm': True
        },
    )
    pay_date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    bank_number = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(validators=[bank_number_validate])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.store.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.bank_number:
            self.bank_number = self.store.bank_number

        if not self.pay_date:
            self.pay_date = datetime.now()

        super(StoreCheckout, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not settings.MIN_CHECKOUT <= self.store.wallet <= settings.MAX_CHECKOUT:
            raise ValidationError(
                f'amount of your store must between {settings.MIN_CHECKOUT} and {settings.MAX_CHECKOUT} toman'
            )

        super(StoreCheckout, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Show us the errors.

Comment: it don have any error, methods not called

Comment: Can you add the model code for `Store` and add some python shell code you're using to test this?

One thing you should try is putting a breakpoint in your methods (`import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`), run your code and investigate what the values are.

Comment: if by chance you are using bulk operations, then be noted that overridden model methods are not called, see more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: thanks every one my problem is solved